# Mysqldump - Drops all external connections

Tags: linux, mysql, putty, winscp

We're completing work for a company with 20 retail locations, and a total of 50 workstations. The project requires 2, or 3 full DB dumps, with an equal amount of imports. This process is standard, and we do it upwards of four times a day without issue. This customer has a **Linux(CentOS)** box, and we've been using a combination of **Putty** & **WinSCP** to complete the dump/upload.

For some reason, when we've dumped the data, or imported an updated set of data back into a new database, all of the external connections are dropping. We're still able to connect via WinSCP/Putty. The logs do not shed much light on this matter either, as it's not even recognizing the external connection attempt. As soon as the dump/import is complete, every workstation connects immediately(we have a applet & driver that looks for the open port). Does anyone have any ideas, answers, or troubleshooting suggestions? Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: What DB engine is being used? Are you able to connect to the mysql db manually from an "external connection" while mysqldump is running? (I don't mean ssh'ing into the host; I mean, can you connect to the mysql db during the dump.) By default, `mysqldump` locks all the tables it is dumping. Is it possible the workstations are detecting the locked tables and are disconnecting?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Much appreciated! They are currently running mysql 5.0. No, we are unable to connect externally. We've tried testing through our applet, CMD, and we even tried to telnet the IP & port, which during the dump, appears to be offline. We normally expect some minor issues from the client-side machines, with all of the locked tables. However, our product's DB has 200-300 active tables, and they aren't all locked at once. 

I'm not sure if it helps, but the database in this particular scenario is almost 12GB.

Comment: Ah, by mysql engine I meant like, what engine is the MySQL database using? InnoDB? ISAM? Unfortunately, I cannot really think of what would be causing this issue of making the entire host inaccessible during a mysqldump. Resource constraints, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If the locked tables are what's contributing to the dropped connection issue, you might try adding --single-transaction to your dump command.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction)